# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error when JSON requested on hosting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have problem with my app in asp.net mvc.
On my app I use FullCalendar jQuery whith events requested in a JSON array. jQueryCalendar looks like below.

```
function renderCalendar() {
    $("#cal").fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay, month'
        },
        height: 'auto',
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: false,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
        eventLimit: true,
        businessHours: {                
            start: '07:00',
            end: '23:00'
        },
        eventLimitClick: 'day',
        views: {
            month: {
                eventLimit: 8
            }
        },
        lang: 'pl',
        displayEventEnd: true,
        timeFormat: {
            month: "HH:mm"
        },

        events: {
            url: '/Schedules/GetEvents/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                department_term: current_department,
            }
        },
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#cal')
                .fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');

            $('#cal')
                .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date.format());
        }
    });
```

My controller action looks like below:

```
    public JsonResult GetEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, string   department_term)
        {
            operations to generating listOfEvents
            var results = listOfEvents.ToArray();
            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Everything works fine on local-host in my visual. But I have to deploy the app to somme.com and now if I open the calendar I get a NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error (watching in firebug in firefox). I find in firebug that the headline of the answer has a Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8 instead of 
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8 - like on local-host.
What could it be?

Please help me.

http://staff-net.somee.com/Schedules/Calendar

**To melaspelas**
I added to my config code like you said. This is it.

```
<system.webServer>      
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>  
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

But that still isn't work.

I still have in my Answer Header:

```
Content-Length      75
Content-Type        text/html
Date        Fri, 15 May 2015 10:45:26 GMT
Server      Microsoft-IIS/8.5
```

and in Request Header:

```
Accept      application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Accept-Language     pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Content-Type        application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie      b=b; ... <lot of text>
Host        staff-net.somee.com
Referer     http://staff-net.somee.com/Schedules/Calendar
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

**To peinearydevelopment:**
Your parameter don't change anything.

**On localhost in Visual Studio i have:**

in my Answer Header:

```
    Cache-Control   private, s-maxage=0
Content-Length  15263
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Fri, 15 May 2015 15:16:56 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 5.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbGtvemxvd3NraVxEb2N1bWVudHNcVmlzdWFsIFN0dWRpbyAyMDEzXFByb2plY3RzXFNUQUZGLk5FVFxTVEFGRi5ORVRcU2NoZWR1bGVzXEdldEV2ZW50c1w
=?=
```

and in Request Header:

```
    Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encodingg     zip, deflate
    Accept-Language pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cookie  __RequestVerificationToken=LI...
Host    localhost:50206
Referer http://localhost:50206/Schedules/Calendar
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

**And on hosting i have:**

Answer Header

```
Cache-Control   private, s-maxage=0
Content-Length  2903
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Fri, 15 May 2015 15:27:00 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 5.0
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

Request Header:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cookie  b=b; b=b; questVerificationToke...
Host    staff-net.somee.com
Referer http://staff-net.somee.com/Schedules/Calendar
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: did you check the mime/type in your IIS??

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read the information's from your link but my app is deploy on hosting and i haven't access to configuration of server. Is there another way to fix it? For example in local Web.config of my app?

Comment: I updated my answer with web.config settings

Comment: I update my question with your leads. So there is no way to fix it without a configure the IIS? So in this case there is no solution?

Comment: Maybe you are getting a real error, you could turn off the custom errors of ASP.net. 


<customErrors mode="Off"/>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to specify the Content-Type like this:

```
events: {
  url: '/Schedules/GetEvents/',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  data: {
    department_term: current_department,
}
```

This plugin seems to be using $.ajax in the background. You can set settings on it as documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Did that change the answer header to not contain Content-Type        text/html? What is the content response that you get locally that works and what is the content response that you get remotely that doesn't work?

Comment: I was updated my question with answer to you question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you need to add the mime type json to your IIS, pls check this:

Run as command to run IIS Manager as an administrator -> In Run as type: inetmgr

Then ([check this link](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true) for detailed steps)

1. In IIS Manager, right-click the Web site or Web site directory for which you want to add a MIME type, and click Properties.
2. Click the HTTP Headers tab.
3. Click Mime Types.
4. Click New.
5. In the Extension box, type the file name extension.
6. In the MIME type box, type a description that exactly matches the file type defined on the computer. If you define a MIME type that has already been defined at a higher level, you are prompted to select the level where the MIME type should reside.
7. Click OK.

Or in your web config you can do this:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

I hope this helps,

Regards